# How to call a method from cell renderer in ag grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

In my React app using Hooks, I am using a AgGrid and want to invoke some function within cellRenderer.

```
{
  headerName: 'Link Text',
  field: 'someId',
  width: 160,
  cellRenderer: renderLinkRenderer
}
```

Below is my renderLinkRenderer;

```
import React from 'react';
export default (props) => {

    const goToDetails = (params) => {
        //How do I invoke this function ?
    }
  
   return <a href="javascript:;" onClick="goToDetails()">{props.value}</a>
};
```

Using onClick as above does not invoke the function. What can I try next?

Comment: When or how are you wanting, or trying, to invoke it. As it's currently written it's a callback function that is called in response to the anchor link being clicked.

Comment: yeah right, I want to invoke it when the link is clicked and I want to navigate to some route and on that route, I want to leverage the grid/row data as well.

Comment: What is the route/path you want to navigate to? Are you using any routing/navigation library? Can you [edit] the post to include a complete [mcve] for the component rendering the grid?

Comment: You can create a custom column type where you set the renderer and pass them some properties. https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-properties/#reference-styling. Search "cellRendererParams" in my link.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function instead, however onClick takes a function as argument, not its return value, so you just have to remove the parenthesis:

```
 return <a href="javascript:;" onClick="goToDetails">{props.value}</a>
```

Comment: cellRenderer: function (params) {

                   if (typeof params.value != 'number' && !params.value && typeof params.value !== 'boolean') {
                    return '';
                   } else return params.value;
                  }
                 }